# How to disable submit button based on input field arrays validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am making a form to order items stored in a database. Each item has an input field for the number of items that are to be ordered. The code for each item looks like this.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="item13">409 Carpet Cleaner</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" div="">
    <div class="has-success has-feedback">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemID[]" value="13">
        <input type="hidden" name="metaID[]" value="73">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="item13" name="quantity[]" min="0" max="10" value="0">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <span class="text-success"> X 1 case (12 aerosol cans)</span>
</div>
```

That HTML just gets added and repeated to the page dynamically from my database by PHP depending on how many items there are. (Right now they 113 items in my form, since why I'm using arrays in the name attribute)

My submit button is like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" id="submitOrder">Submit Order For Entire Store Location</button>
```

And my validation script is as follows:

```
$("input[name='quantity[]']").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var maxValue = $(this).attr('max');
    var minValue = $(this).attr('min');
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');

    maxValue = parseInt(maxValue);
    minValue = parseInt(minValue);
    value = parseInt(value);

    //console.log("we was called " + minValue + " " + value + " " + maxValue + " " + itemID);

    if(value > maxValue || value < minValue){

        //console.log("wrong number");
        $("#submitOrder").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#f36e65");

    }else{
        $("#submitOrder").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#43C56D");      
    }
});
```

So what I want to do is that if any input field fail to meet the validation, to keep the submit button disabled. Right now it disables it if an input fails but if another similar input field is typed in after that and meets the validation then the submit button is enabled, even though the previous input failed it.

How can I keep track of the errors and disable the button if there are any and enable it once they're fixed.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

You can keep a map and store the validation failure result in that map.

```
var map = {}; // map that stores validation failures
$("input[name='quantity[]']").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var maxValue = $(this).attr('max');
    var minValue = $(this).attr('min');
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');

    maxValue = parseInt(maxValue);
    minValue = parseInt(minValue);
    value = parseInt(value);

     if(value > maxValue || value < minValue){
        map[itemID] = false; // add validation failure result in map
        $("#submitOrder").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#f36e65");
    }else{
        delete map[itemID]; // delete validation failure result from map
        if(Object.keys(map).length === 0) { // If no validation error, remove disabled attribute
          $("#submitOrder").removeAttr("disabled");    
        }
        $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#43C56D");  

    }
});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/pnLssObOHquOAwwkmVbW?p=preview

Comment: Ok, let me try that real quick.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom attribute, e.g. `data-pass`, as `false` when test is failed, e.g.:

```
    if(value > maxValue || value < minValue){
       $("#submitOrder").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#f36e65");

       // write attribute to false
       $(this).attr('data-pass', false);

    } else {

       // write attribute to true
       $(this).attr('data-pass', true);

       // check all inputs don't have false values for that attribute
       if ( $('input[data-pass="false"]').length === 0 ) {
           $("#submitOrder").removeAttr("disabled");
           $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#43C56D");
       }  
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that all inputs don't have to be changed. I could maybe do the opposite and marked them as `true` from the start since they get a value 0 to start off, which is passes validation. If it fails validation then change the data-pass attribute to false.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried @nikhil idea of making a "map" and it worked. Thank you for your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your validation function, check values of all input tags of the form (not only the tag that just changed).

For instance (Update: 2016-01-19):

```
$("input[name='quantity[]']").on("keyup", function() {
    var ok = true;
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("input[name='quantity[]']").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var maxValue = $(this).attr('max');
        var minValue = $(this).attr('min');
        maxValue = parseInt(maxValue);
        minValue = parseInt(minValue);
        value = parseInt(value);
        if ((value > maxValue) || (value < minValue)){
            ok = false;
            if ($(this).attr('id') == itemID){
                $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#f36e65");
            }
        }else if ($(this).attr('id') == itemID){
            $('#' + itemID).css("background-color","#43C56D");
        }
    });
    if (ok){
        $("#submitOrder").removeAttr("disabled");
    }else{
        $("#submitOrder").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that all inputs have the same name, are set to 0 by default when the PHP makes them and they all don't need to by changed. Only the items to be ordered would change.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by "they all don't need to by changed". I added a code sample.

Comment: So basically it is a long form currently 113 input fields. They all have a starting value of `0` which can be changed to a higher value to order it. But they don't have to order every item and can just leave it as 0. So I had to keep track of which inputs were changed and if this change gave out an error. @nikhil posted a pretty nifty answer of using a "map" which worked. Thank you for your help nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!